# How to effectively pass data from my controller to repository, Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony project that makes use of a

Repository file in which I have declared and created an instance of a query builder

(repository1)

```
$mk = $this->createQueryBuilder('up');

        $later = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-3 months"));
        $today = date("Y-m-d");
        
        $mk->andWhere('up.period BETWEEN :start AND :end');
        $mk->setParameter('start', $later);
        $mk->setParameter('end', $today);

        return $mk->getQuery()->getResult();
```

automatically this generates data for my page between the above dates.

Now I want to create a form where I can make a search between two dates.

with the intention of passing the posted data from this form to my controller into my method below

My controller below (controller1)

```
    protected function getData(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,Request $request) {
    
    // this code to get data from repository
    $entityManager->getRepository(repository1::class)->getName()

// receive posted data
 $date1 = $request->get('date');
 $date2 = $request->get('date');

    // now how to pass data to my repository1
    
    }
```

Please how do I edit what I have to post data from within my controller to my (repository1)

so then it would be

```
  $mk = $this->createQueryBuilder('up');
    
            $later = $date1;
            $today = $date2;
            
            $mk->andWhere('up.period BETWEEN :start AND :end');
            $mk->setParameter('start', $later);
            $mk->setParameter('end', $today);
    
            return $mk->getQuery()->getResult();
```

is this even possible, or im over thinking it?

Comment: For your question, add them as arguments to `repository1::getName($date1 = null, $date2 = null);` Then add a condition for when the arguments are `null` to set default values. However, I highly recommend using [queries as a service instead of the doctrine repository](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/). You can then use dependency injection along with  `__invoke($date1, $date2);` to retrieve the desired data from the query builder.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the issue and what specifically are you having issues with? Are you needing to check if the request is a post request or are you using a separate route? I would believe if you're working with Symfony that adding arguments to a method would be considered a trivial matter for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the dates as parameters to your method.

Controller Class:

```
protected function getData(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,Request $request) {

    $start = $request->get('start') ? new \DateTime($request->get('start')) : null;
    $end = $request->get('end') ? new \DateTime($request->get('end')) : null;
    $result = $entityManager->getRepository(Entity::class)->getName($start, $end);

    // do with result as desired
}
```

Repository Class:

```
public function getName(\DateTimeInterface $start, \DateTimeInterface $end)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('up')
                ->andWhere('up.period BETWEEN :start AND :end')
                ->setParameter('start', $start)
                ->setParameter('end', $end)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RepositoryClass

```
public function getByStartEndDate(DateTimeInterface $start, DateTimeInterface $end)
{
  return $this->createQueryBuilder('up')
    ->andWhere('up.period BETWEEN :start AND :end')
    ->setParameter('start', $start)
    ->setParameter('end', $end)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
  ;
}
```

Controller Class

```
private function getData(Request $request, RepositoryClass $repo)
{
  // May need to convert these to DateTime objects
  $start = $request->get('start');
  $end = $request->get('end');

  $records = $repo->getByStartEndDate($start, $end);

  // do what you want with the records here
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. `->get('start')` and `$start` and `$end` is not a DateTimeInterface Instance.

Comment: Yeah I mention that in my inline comment in the controller class

Comment: yes but you still have a typo in `->get->('start')` :-)

Comment: You do realise you have a typo in your start AND end assignment right? I guess you are also human haha

Comment: true on both accounts :)